# What do Trainer Levelups Do?

Tags: penny-arcade-4

In Penny Arcade's On the Rainslick Precipice of Darkness 4, both trainers and monsters levelup.  I understand that monster's gain attributes on levelup and that both monsters and trainers gain abilities *on certain levels* but what about the levels where the trainers *don't* gain an ability?  What effect do those levelups have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No effect, really.  Trainer levelups only grant new abilities, much like the class pins in Penny Arcade 3.